# Баги с Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Прописал

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */*{padding:0; margin:0; width: 100%; height: 100vh;}
```

но IE не видит `height: 100vh`

Comment: что можно сделать?

Comment: Какая версия IE?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: @AlexAnder Попробуйте использовать более специфичный селектор, вместо `*` напишите, например, `body`

Comment: к сожалению не помогло. вообще не видит

Comment: какие могут быть альтернативы?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо vh и vw используем проценты, но чтобы работала высота в процентах нужно родительскому элементу тоже указать высоту:

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  float: left;
  width: 32.333333%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  height: 49%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если прописать высоту дважды.

Сначала - `height`: "высота для ие и тех браузеров, что не знают vh"
А потом - `height: 100vh`

Браузеры которые знают эту величину возьмут `height: 100vh` и перетрут прежнюю высоту. А которые не знают - возьмут предыдущий `height:`